# Repeating webhook ODOO - Ignore external requests?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-14

In odoo, I'm inheriting the create, write and unlink methods in odoo to send a webhook whenever these methods are called. The webhook is working, however it's being called repeatedly until I force odoo to restart. The webhook triggers another module that inturn updates the record a 2nd time, Odoo's then triggering the write method again (because the record has been updated from the other module). Is it possible to only envoke this write method when triggered from its own module and ignore any other modules?

```
def write(self, vals):
    record = super().write(vals)
    self.ensure_one()
    self.message_post(body="<strong style=\"color: #03355b\">Document Updated</strong>")
    record = super().write(vals)
    url = '########'
    webhook_data = {
        'post_title': self.title,
        'folder': self.folder,
        'post_content': self.post_content,
        'portal_id': self.id,
        'status': self.status,
        'webhook_action': 'update'
        }
    response = requests.post(
        url, data=json.dumps(webhook_data),
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authentication': '####'}
    )
    return record
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution, but just in case it helps anyone else..

The first trigger doesn't update the color field, whilst the returning webhook does. So I've added `if not 'color' in vals:` to the start of the method and it's then ignoring the second http request.